# Passing parameters to cypher query through neo4j-shell

Tags: neo4j

I was wondering whether there is a way to pass parameters to a Cypher query through the neo4j-shell. Although the details of the query may not matter, I want to execute the following query through neo4j-shell:

```
MATCH (src:Node{id:1}),(dst:Node{id:2}),
  p = shortestPath((src)-[*..15]-(dst))
RETURN p;
```

What I do is put this inside a file query.cql and then execute it by running neo4j-shell -file query.cql. However, every time I run it I may want to change the source and destination IDs. So ideally, I'd like my query to be something like this:

```
MATCH (src:Node{id:srcid}),(dst:Node{id:dstid}),
  p = shortestPath((src)-[*..15]-(dst))
RETURN p;
```

and define srcid and dstid in the command line. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [use the export command](http://java.dzone.com/articles/neo4j-cypher).

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ export myParam="Foo"
neo4j-sh (?)$ CREATE (u:Node {label: {myParam}});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
Properties set: 1
Labels added: 1
10 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (u:Node {label: {myParam}}) return u.label;
+---------+
| u.label |
+---------+
| "Foo"   |
+---------+
1 row
19 ms
```

**EDIT** if you wanted to do this from the shell before entering interactive query, you can use a neat little bash trick, like this:

```
$ { echo "export foo='bar'" ; cat; } | neo4j-shell -path my.db
```

This has a big drawback though; the line-editing functions of neo4j-shell won't be available; you'll just be feeding it interactive data via `cat` so it's not truly interactive.

Normally, this would be solved by using an initfile containing some cypher commands that would get loaded every time during each interactive session, but as far as I know neo4j-shell doesn't support that, so this bash trick is the best I can offer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you know if there is a way to do this though without entering the interactive neo4j-shell environment? I'm trying to do this from a bash shell, and doing the equivalent (doing an export in bash) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Edited answer to address your follow-on question.

Comment: The last suggestion did it. To be more precise, in my case I re-write query.cql as:

    `MATCH (src:Node{id:{srcid}}),(dst:Node{id:{dstid}}),
      p = shortestPath((src)-[*..15]-(dst))
    RETURN p;`
---
and then run:

    `{ echo "export srcid=1"; echo "export dstid=2"; cat query.cql; } | neo4j-shell -c`